# Share same Firebase db with multiple users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make an app that will have multiple users and I need that all of them share the same database. So when one user add or modify data locally, those changes are synced to other users when they become online. Is this possible with Firebase? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much the purpose of the Firebase Database. But instead of answering "yes", I recommend that you take the [Firebase codelab, which shows you how build a multi-user application](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). For a more sit-back-and-see-it-experience, watch [our Zero to App from Google I/O last week, where we built a multi-user photo-sharing app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01M_hZav9Gw).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some events such as ValueEventListener or ChildEventListener to listener for the change of Data on Firebase, and **Cast** the data to the object.

```
 ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            YourPOJO changedData = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourPOJO.class);
            //Do whatever you want here
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

You can use **changedData** object to refresh data of the views.

Answer (score 0):

just simply use the same reference/url (https://[FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/) for all the users. thats it. visit [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2) for a detailed example.

Comment: Oka. I will try! Thanks.